# Regular expression for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, google-chrome

The following regular expression is working with Internet Explorer, but it does not work Firefox or Chrome.

```
function CheckValidText(comment) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9\*]{1}+[A-Za-z0-9[:blank:]]*");
    var regExpr = new RegExp(regex);

    var result = comment.search(regExpr);
    if (comment.search(regExpr) != -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this bit: `{1}+`

With `{1}`, you're specifiying exactly one of the preceding item.... but then with the `+`, you're specifying one or more of them. They're in conflict with each other.

Depending on your requirements, you need to either drop the `{1}` or the `+`.

If you remove one or other of those then the code does work in Firefox. (tested using Firebug)

However, as @Guffa says, you do seem to have some odd logic where you're creating one regex object from another -- it does seem to work, but it's really not a good thing, and may cause you other problems (I haven't tried it in Chrome yet).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `RegExp` object to create another `RegExp` object, which should not work in any browser. Just use a string:

```
var regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9\*]{1}+[A-Za-z0-9[:blank:]]*";
var regExpr = new RegExp(regex);
```